# Python - put functions under subpackage namespace without .py files

Tags: python, package

I think it's a simple question associate with package of python, while I have no idea what the keyword is and found nothing on the Internet. The title might not be clear, let me explain with example in the following.

So I have a habit to keep miscellaneous functions in my own package, for example:

```
mytools
|---__init__.py
|---plt_cb_miscs.py
|---project_miscs.py
|---datum_conv.py
```

Of course, as I `import mytools.project_miscs as pmisc`, I can call functions such as `pmisc.is_oddnum`, `pmisc.read_logcsv`, `pmisc.plot_allfig`...etc which are defined inside `project_miscs.py`.

Now, say the code of `pmisc.plot_allfig` had grown too large. I want to put it into individual *.py* file while keeping it under namespace `project_XXX_misc`.

I'm thinking of making `project_misc` into a subpackage:

```
mytools
|---__init__.py
|---plt_cb_miscs.py
|---project_miscs
    |---__init__.py
    |---plot_allfig.py
    |---...
|---datum_conv.py
```

But there're still tiny functions, like `is_oddnum`, that I want to keep them in a same *.py* file and call them from `mytools.project_miscs.is_oddnum` without separate it into `is_oddnum.py`. Is there a way to do this? Or should I desert this thought and create another *.py* to collect them under directory `project_miscs`?

Comment: If I correctly understood your question: yes. Put your small functions into `__init__.py` of your `project_miscs` package. Import the function(s) from `plot_allfig.py` in the same `__init__.py` like so: `from .plot_allfig import plot_allfig`. Then you can simply `import project_miscs as pmisc` and do `pmisc.is_oddnum()` as well as `pmisc.plot_allfig()`

Comment: @shmee Oh wow that's exactly what I want ! Thank you so much. I thought `__init__.py` is equivalent to `def __init__():` in a class, and could be wierd to put other **def** statement inside it (since we usually put **def** after done declaring `def __init__():`). Do you want to reply it as answer so that I can pick it and close this post?

Comment: In a way, you actually _can_ consider the `__init__.py` file a package's equivalent of the `__init__()` method. And in Python, it's perfectly fine to declare functions inside functions. As for the putting this as an answer: Nah, there's enough resources out there (probably even on SO) that explain Pythons's import system and the `__init__.py` in a more generic way. I don't feel that such a specific answer would add much for SO and I'm not that desperate for rep :) Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Alright, still many thanks for your help :) And I'll go check the details of the Python import system.